# Memory Management Questions

Tags: objective-c

I have been programming in Objective-C for a couple weeks now, and I think its time that I think more about my memory management and so I have a couple scenarios I would like clarification on.

```
NSString *myString = @"Hello, World";
```

If I were to on the next line do

```
NSString *anotherString = myString;
```

Is it getting copied? or is another string just a pointer to myString? if it's just a pointer how would I make anotherString a copy of myString that has its own memory?

What if I were to

```
[anotherString release];
```

What actually gets released, just anotherString, or does myString go away too?

Then if I were to do

```
anotherString = nil;
```

Does that actually free up memory and for use or does it still have the space allocated with empty memory? Obviously the pointer can still be used. What does it do to myString?

This will really help me become better at managing the memory properly, instead of just `[object release];` randomly and causing crashes.

Thank you VERY MUCH in advance to whoever replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
NSString *myString = @"Hello, World";
NSString *anotherString = myString;
```

...you're creating a single `NSString` instance, and two pointers to it.  So to answer your questions, no it is not being copied.  Yes, `anotherString` is just a pointer, and so is `myString`, the actual `NSString` instance is off in memory-land, at the address that both pointers are now pointing to.

To make a copy of the string, you would do:

```
NSString *anotherString = [myString copy];
```

When you do:

```
[anotherString release];
```

The `NSString` instance that `anotherString` points to is released.  Nothing happens to `anotherString` itself.  It continues to point to your now-invalidated object instance.  If `myString` was pointing to the same instance, then yes, this causes `myString` to "go away" as well.

And if you do:

```
anotherString = nil;
```

...then you've caused a memory leak, because you reassigned the pointer without releasing the thing it was pointing at.  Except not in this case because `@"Hello, World"` is a literal value that is loaded onto the stack and is not retained by your code.

In any case, setting `anotherString` to `nil` does nothing to your string, it just changes what `anotherString` points to.  Your actual `NSString` instance is still off in memory-land, completely unaware that you just threw away your reference to it (possible exception:  reference counted/garbage collected environments).

And yes, calling `[object release]` randomly will cause crashes.  As a general rule you should only call `release` on something if:

1. You called `alloc` and `init...` on it.
2. You called `retain` on it.
3. You obtained the object as a result of calling `copy` on some other object.

Note that these stack, so if you `alloc` something, `retain` it, and then `copy` it, you need to have 3 calls to `release`, two for the object that you `alloc`'ed, and one for the copy.

As a side note, you may find it clearer to write your object declarations like:

```
NSString* myString = @"Hello, World";
NSString* anotherString = myString;
```

...which makes it more obvious that what you are declaring are *pointers to NSString's* and not NSString's themselves.  Personally I think your original syntax, while commonly used, is also [backwards](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/270).

Answer (score 0):

This string:

```
NSString *myString = @"Hello, World";
```

is created on the stack. It's loaded into memory when the app starts. You don't own the memory backing the object, and therefore shouldn't release it.

If you want to copy a string to the heap (where you can manage the memory), you simply do this:

```
NSString *anotherString = [myString copy];
```

Then you're responsible for releasing that object when you're done with it.

```
[anotherString release];
```

Setting a pointer to nil just clears the pointer, not the object it's pointing to. It's still in memory.

Answer (score 0):

NSString *anotherString = myString;

--- This is just a pointer assignment

--- You can copy myString using [myString copy]

[anotherString release];

--- You are releasing the owner ship of the anotherString (please read about retain count concept)

anotherString = nil;

--- you are just assigning the pointer to nothing.

I suggest Please read more about memory management apple documents ...